# How to extend configs with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, configuration, requirejs, config

Im using RequireJS for my coding. I have one source base, but have few different frontends.
These frontends should use different sets of modules, so I have to support few RequireJS configs, each for different product. Adding module to one config, cause adding it to few additional configs.

Is there way to inherit/extend RequireJS configs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you give multiple configurations to RequireJS, it will combine them. For instance if you first make this call:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        foo: "path/to/foo",
        bar: "path/to/bar"
    }
});
```

And then this second call:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        foo: "some/other/path/to/foo",
        baz: "path/to/baz"
    }
});
```

These two will be combined so that `bar` still has the path defined in the first `require.config` call. However, `foo` will be overridden by the second config. And `baz` won't be resolved as `path/to/baz` until the 2nd config is read.

There are limitations however. For instance, you can give an array as a `paths` setting for a specific module. For instance, `foo: ["/some/path", "another/path"]`. RequireJS will try the paths in order when you require `foo`. However, there is no method to tell RequireJS in a subsequent call to `require.config` to take whatever array was set earlier and just *add* another value to the array. You'd have to give `require.config` the *whole* array in a subsequent call.

Comment: There is no RequireJS interface to do something like `require.readConfigFromFile`. However, you can put your calls to `require.config` inside a module if it fits your use-case scenario and since a module is a file.

Answer (score 1):

Louis' answer is right, but just a note, it is possible to read from multiple configs when using the `r.js` optimizer. According to the [example build file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L35-L37) you can pass an array of values to the mainConfigFile, with the latter taking precedence over the former.